# How to save table data in session

Tags: php, session

I have problem in little project,
how can I save table data in session?

```
<?php
        session_start();
        include 'connect.php';
            if (isset($_POST["email"]))
            {
                $email = $_POST["email"];
                $password = $_POST["password"];
                $r=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM user_login WHERE `uemail` ='".$email."'   AND `upass` =           '".$password."'");
                $s = $_POST["userid"];
                $n=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM user_data WHERE `userid` ='".$s."'");
                $q=mysql_fetch_assoc($n);
                $_SESSION["name"]=$q["nfname"];
                $k=mysql_num_rows($r);
                if ($k>0)
                {
                header("location:user/index.php");
                }
                else 
                header("location:login.php");
            }

                ?>
```

this code not working !! :(
please help !

Comment: What i snot working? What have you done to debug this? FYI, your code is obsolete and insecure.

Comment: I'ma try and be a lil nicer than John (no offense John). Read up on [PDO](http://us2.php.net/pdo) as your current method is deprecated and will be obsolete soon. Plus its insecure.

Comment: You probably forgot `session_start()`.

Comment: @13ruce1337: "nicer" becomes difficult when you see the EXACT same crappy code and exact same logic errors day after day after day.

Comment: your not fetching first query

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I'll bite. First 13ruce1337, and Marc B are right. There is a lot more wrong with this than  not being able to get your data into your session.

Using PDO ( as 13ruce1337 links you too ) is a must. If you want to keep using the same style of mysql functions [start reading up on how](https://www.php.net/mysqli). Marc B points out that `session_start();` before any html output is required for sessions to work.

As for your code, you got along ways to go before it is ready for use but here is an example to get you started

```
if (isset($_POST["email"])) {
    
    //mysql_ functions are being deprecated you can instead use
    //mysqli_ functions read up at https://www.php.net/mysqli
    
    /* Manage your post data. Clean it up, etc dont just use $_POST data */
    foreach($_POST as $key =>$val) { 
        $$key = mysqli_real_escape_string($link,$val);
        /* ... filter your data ... */
    }
    
    if ($_POST["select"] == "user"){
    $r = mysqli_query($link,"SELECT * FROM user_login WHERE `uemail` ='$email' AND `upass` = '$password'");
    /* you probably meant to do something with this query? so do it*/
    
    $n = mysqli_query($link,"SELECT * FROM user_data WHERE userid ='$userid'");
    //$r=mysql_fetch_assoc($n); <- this overrides your user_login query
    $t = mysqli_fetch_array($n);
    
    $_SESSION["name"] = $t['nfname'];
    
    /* ... whatever else you have going on */
```

Answer (score 0):

You probably just missed the

```
session_start();
```

But here is the dildo (deal tho) xD

Your Login script is not secure, try this at the top of your index.php or whatever rootfile you have.

```
<?php

session_start();

function _login($email, $password) {
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM user_login
            WHERE MD5(uemail) ='".md5(mysql_real_escape_string($email))."' 
            AND MD5(upass) = '".md5(mysql_real_escape_string($password))."'";
    $qry = mysql_query($sql);
    if(mysql_num_rows($qry) > 0) {
        // user with that login found!
        $sql = "UPDATE user_login SET uip = '".$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']."', usession = '".session_id()."'";
        mysql_query($sql);
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}

function _loginCheck() {
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM user_login WHERE uip = '".$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']."' AND MD5(usession) = '".md5(session_id())."'";
    $qry = mysql_query($sql);
    if(mysql_num_rows($qry) > 0) {
        // user is logged in
        $GLOBALS['user'] = mysql_fetch_object($qry);
        $GLOBALS['user']->login = true;
    } else {
        // user is not logged in
        $GLOBALS['user'] = (object) array('login' => false);
    }
}

if(isset($_POST['login'])) {
    if(_login($_POST["email"], $_POST["password"])) {
        // login was successfull
    } else {
        // login failed
    }
}

_loginCheck(); // checkes every Page, if the user is logged in or if not

if($GLOBALS['user']->login === true) {
    // this user is logged in :D
}

?>
```